# Maximum height when opening a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I make a max height?

```
animate( { height: '500px' } to animate( { height: '100%' }
```

I have some heights with `200px 300px 400px 800px`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#updo").click(function(){
        $("#updo_folder").stop();
        $("#updo_folder").show();
        if($("#updo_folder").height() < 1){
            $("#updo_folder").animate( { height: '500px' }, 1000 , function(){$(this).show();});
        }else{
            $("#updo_folder").animate( { height: '0px' }, 1000, function(){$(this).hide();});
        }
    });

});
var jump=function(e)
{
       e.preventDefault();
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
       $('html,body').animate(
       {
           scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
       },500,function()
       {
               location.hash = target;
       });

}

$(document).ready(function()
{
       $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
       return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prffrost/TFBeu/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `height: 100%`, measure it, then set `height: 0px` again and animate to that height:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#updo").click(function () {
        // Use a variable rather than endlessly repeating the lookup
        var folder = $("#updo_folder");
        var targetHeight;
        folder.stop().show();
        if (folder.height() < 1) {
            // Set it to full height
            folder.css("height", "100%");
            // Measure it
            targetHeight = folder.height();
            // Set back to zero height, and animate to the measured height
            folder.css("height", "0px");
            folder.animate({
                height: targetHeight
            }, 1000, function () {
                $(this).show();
            });
        } else {
            folder.animate({
                height: '0px'
            }, 1000, function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
    });

});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFBeu/6/)